# How can I multiply two strings containing 'huge numbers' (over 30 digits)?

Tags: c, string

I'm doing school project which I'm needed to first receive 2 huge numbers (unlimited size, for the sake of example, lets say over 30 digits), second step is to take the 2 input numbers the create new number of the multiplication of the two, which I'm really breaking a sweat trying to do so.

My code so far:

Type definition to making sure I'm handling the right variables:

```
typedef char* verylong;
#define MAX_SIZE 100
```

Input method:

```
verylong input_long() {
    int i, len; //i for loop, len for strlen - using integer for it to avoid invoking the method more than 1 time
    verylong number;
    char temp_str[MAX_SIZE];    //the input from user - limited to 100

    gets(temp_str); //user input
    len = strlen(temp_str); //saving the length of the input
    number = (char*)calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));  //allocating memory for the verylong and saving space for \0

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (temp_str[i] - '0' < 0 || temp_str[i] - '0' > 9) {   //the input is not a digit
            printf("\nBad input!\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        number[i] = temp_str[i];    //all is good -> add to the verylong number
    }
    number[i] = '\0';   //setting last spot

    return number;
}
```

My sad attempt of completing my task:

```
verylong multiply_verylong(verylong vl1, verylong vl2) {
    verylong mult;
    int cur, i, j, k, lrg, sml, temp_size;
    char *temp;

    j = 1;
    temp = (char*)calloc(lrg + sml + 1, sizeof(char)); //maximum amount of digits


    if (strlen(vl1) > strlen(vl2)) {
        lrg = strlen(vl1);
        sml = strlen(vl2);
    }
    else {
        lrg = strlen(vl2);
        sml = strlen(vl1);
    }

    cur = 0;

    for (i = sml-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        k = 0;
        temp_size = 0;
        cur = (vl1[i] - '0')*(vl2[i] - '0');
        printf("\ncur=%d", cur);
        if (cur > 9)
            temp_size = 2;
        else
            temp_size = 1;
        while (k < temp_size) {
            if (cur > 9)
                temp[j++] = (cur % 10) + '0';
            else
                temp[j++] = cur + '0';
            cur /= 10;
            k++;
        }
    }

    mult = (char*)calloc(j + 1, sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        mult[i] = temp[i];
    }
    mult[i] = '\0';
    free(temp);
    return mult;
}
```

Long story short, I know I'm doing mistake at my multiplication method since I'm adding the numbers by simply adding the mult of 2 digits at a time, over that I truly am lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Follow up, why do you think that just adding up the product of digits is wrong? What did you learn in school about multiplying two numbers with more than one digit? Brush up on doing it on paper. Then do it by program.

Comment: Note, hiding a pointer inside a typedef often, practically always, gets you into trouble. So don't do `typedef char* verylong;`.

Comment: In `multiply_verylong()` you are using `lrg` and `sml` in `calloc()` with undefined values.

Comment: Just a side note: one or both of those numbers might have a `-` in front, I guess.

Comment: @Yunnosch example: if I'm taking 888*999 instead of getting 8887112 I'll get 727272, the reason for the typedef it's the assignment demand.
thebusybee I know, that's the result of my trying more stuff and not paying attention, but that's not the issue
hyde as I said to Yunnosch , it's not my call
domsson only unsigned numbers

Comment: If you want to reach multiple users, better use one comment with an @ for each. And in my case, giving an example will not help you much. It only becomes clear if you describe generally. From there you can derive an algorithm. You do remember how to multiply numbers on paper, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice would be to break the task into a number of simpler task.

How would you do the multiplication on paper?

```
123 * 456 ->  1 * (456 * 100) + 2 * (456 * 10) + 3 * (456 * 1)
```

or written differently

```
   3 * (  1 * 456)
 + 2 * ( 10 * 456)
 + 1 * (100 * 456)
   ---------------
  SUM TO GET RESULT

or

   3 *   456
 + 2 *  4560
 + 1 * 45600
   ---------------
  SUM TO GET RESULT
```

From this you can identify 3 tasks

- Multiplying with powers of 10, i.e. 1, 10, 100, etc. (i.e. add zeros to the end)
- Multiplying a string-number with a single digit
- Adding two string-numbers.

Write simple functions for each of these steps.

```
char* mulPowerOf10(char* sn, unsigned power)
{
    ...
}

char* mulDigit(char* sn, char digit)
{
   ...
}

char* addNumbers(char* snA, char* snB)
{
   ...
}
```

Using these 3 simple functions you can put the real multiplication together. In psedo-code:

```
char* mulNumbers(char* snA, char* snB)
{
    char* result = malloc(2);
    strcpy(result, "0");
    unsigned power = 0;
    for_each_digit D in snA
    {
        char* t1 = mulPowerOf10(snB, power)
        char* t2 = mulDigit(t1, D)
        result = addNumbers(result, t2)
        ++power;
    }

    free(.. what needs to be freed ..);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code can be simplified by converting each character to its value by subtracting '0'. Each byte would then contain a base 10 digit. This also simplify handling of the carry when multiplying with a single digit. At the end, simply add '0' to each digit to get back a string of characters.

Comment: I'm well aware of the mathematical way of doing it, codewise I'm having troubles..

Comment: @RoyRaihenshtein That's why I provide you a way to break down the task into smaller and simpler code pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code example.

I found it simpler to store the number as a sequence of digits along with the length in a struct. The number may have leading zeros.

```c
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

typedef struct Number {
    int len;
    char digits[];
} Number;

// Instantiate a number with room for len digits.
Number *newNumber(int len) {
    Number *n = malloc(sizeof(Number)+len);
    n->len = len;
    memset(n->digits, 0, len);
    return n;
}

// inputNumber reads a number from stdin. It return NULL if the input 
// is invalid, otherwise it returns a Number containing the given digits. 
Number *inputNumber() {
    char temp[MAX_SIZE];
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin) == NULL)
        return NULL; // use fgets because gets is deprecated since C11

    // remove trailing \n if any
    int len = strlen(temp);
    if (len > 0 && temp[len-1] == '\n')
        temp[--len] = '\0';

    // check input validity
    if (len == 0)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (temp[i] < '0' || temp[i] > '9')
            return NULL;

    Number *n = newNumber(len);
    for (int i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
        n->digits[i] = temp[i] - '0';
    return n;
}
```

To multiply two numbers n1 and n2, we multiply n1 with each digit of n2, and accumulate the result shifted on the left by the position of the n2 digit in the final result.

For instance, to multiply 123*456, we compute 123*4 + 123*5*10 + 123*6*100. Note that *10 and *100 are simply left shifts.

We thus need a function that multiplies a number with a digit, and another function that accumulates a number with a left shift in a result number.

```c
// multiply stores the result of n time digit in result.
// Requires the len of result is the len of n + 1.
void multiplyNumber(Number *n, char digit, Number *result) {
    char carry = 0;
    for (int i = r->len-1, j = n->len-1; i > 0; i--, j--) {
        char x = n->digits[j] * d + carry;
        r->digits[i] = x%10;
        carry = x/10;
    }
    r->digits[0] = carry;
}

// accumutateNumber adds n with the left shift s to the number r. 
// Requires the len of r is at least len of n + s + 1. 
void accumulateNumber(Number *n, int s, Number *r) {
    char carry = 0;
    for (int i = r->len-1-s, j = n->len-1; j >= 0; i--, j--) {
        char x = r->digits[i] + n->digits[j] + carry;
        r->digits[i] = x%10;
        carry = x/10;
    }
    r->digits[r->len-1-s-n->len] = carry;
}
```

Finally, we also need a function to print the number

```c
void printNumber(Number *n) {
    int i = 0;
    // skip 0 at the front
    while (i < n->len && n->digits[i] == 0)
        i++;
    if (i == n->len) {
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }
    while (i < n->len)
        putchar(n->digits[i++] + '0');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And this is it. We can now write the main function with the input of the numbers, the multiplication of number 1 with each digit of number 2 and accumulate the result with a shift to get the final result.

```c
int main() {
    printf("number 1: ");
    Number *n1 = inputNumber();
    if (n1 == NULL) {
        printf("number 1 is invalid\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("number 2: ");
    Number *n2 = inputNumber();
    if (n2 == NULL) {
        printf("number 2 is invalid\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Number *r = newNumber(n1->len+n2->len);
    Number *tmp = newNumber(n1->len+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n2->len; i++) {
        multiplyNumber(n1, n2->digits[n2->len-1-i], tmp);
        accumulateNumber(tmp, i, r);
    }

    printf("result: ");
    printNumber(r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think the len in struct Number should be unsigned ;)

Comment: @0x00001F why do you think that ? The maximum length is defined by MAX_SIZE and it is 1024.

Comment: in general when we dealing index's/length we dealing with positive values from 0 to N , so it's to good to use unsigned because it will cover longer range , right !

Comment: @0x00001F unless the range is between 0 and 1024 and the variable is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Here you may have a look at a 'string only' version, multiplying like you would do with a pencil.

It works with 2 loops. The outer loop takes the digits of value2 from the right and multiplies in the inner loop with every digit of value1 from right. The right digit of the multiplication is stored in result, the rest goes in carry for the next inner loop.

At the end of the inner loop, carry is added to result.

After the first outer loop, we have to add previous results to our multiplication.

This is done in `if(!first && *lresp) r += toI(*lresp)`

The final loop moves the result to the start of the char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define toI(x) ((x)-'0')
#define toC(x) ((x)+'0')
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)) ? (a):(b)

char *mul(char *buf1, char *buf2) {
    int size, v1, v2, r, carry=0, first=1;
    char *startp1, *endp1, *lendp1, *startp2, *endp2;
    char *startres, *endres, *resp, *lresp, *result;

    for(endp1 = startp1 = buf1; *endp1; endp1++); // start and endpointer 1st value
    for(endp2 = startp2 = buf2; *endp2; endp2++); // start and end pointer 2nd value

    size = endp2-startp2 + endp1-startp1;  // result size
    startres = endres = resp = result = malloc(size+10); // some reserve

    endres += size+10-1;  // result end pointer 
    for(resp = startres; resp <= endres; resp++) *resp = '\0';  // init result

    for(endp1--, endp2--, resp-=2; endp2>=startp2; endp2--, resp--, first=0) {
        v2 = toI(*endp2);   // current digit of value2
        for(lresp = resp, lendp1 = endp1; lendp1 >= startp1; lendp1--, lresp--) { 
            v1 = toI(*lendp1);  // current digit of value1
            r = v1 * v2 + carry;  // multiply + carry
            if(!first && *lresp) r += toI(*lresp);  // add result of previous loops
            *lresp = toC(r%10);   // store last digit
            carry = r/10;
        }
        for( ; carry != 0; carry /= 10)
            *lresp-- = toC(carry%10);
    }
    // we began right with reserve, now move to start of result
    for(lresp++; lresp < endres; lresp++, startres++)
        *startres=*lresp;
    *startres = '\0';
    return result;
}
int main() {
    char *result = mul("123456789", "12345678");
    printf("\n%s\n", result);
    free(result);
}
```